# How to stop emulated app from running? (Android Studio, 64-bit Win7 SP1)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

[Running Your App -> Run on the Emulator](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#Emulator) clearly explains how to RUN an app from within Android Studio by launching the emulator.

My question is - 
Once I've done that: "How should I STOP the emulated app from running?"

Thought #1 - Use the "Run -> Stop (Ctrl + F2)" option on Android Studio's menu. But, when running my simple Hello-World-type application, that option is disabled.
Accordingly, Ctrl+F2 has no effect.

Thought #2 - Close the emulator window, by right-clicking the emulator's icon in my task bar, and selecting "Close window."
That closed the application all right, but then it seemed to leave things in a strange state.
-- When I tried to run the application again, it gave an error and I had to recreate the project.
That happened repeatably.

Thought #3 - Try shutting down the (emulated) Android device.
I tried that on Saturday evening: I held down the (emulated) Power button. Clicked the option in the "Device options" window.
It's now Monday morning, and it still says that it's "Shutting down...".

So, "How should I stop the emulated app from running?"

Thank you for any suggestions/help you can provide.

```
Russell
```

---

I now see that I had asked the wrong question.
I should have asked how to stop a running emulator.

Although I had been able to do so by right-clicking the emulator's entry in the task bar, and selecting "Close window", that had SEEMED to cause some problems.
["The selected device is incompatible" was displayed in the "Device Chooser" dialog.]
So, I thought that was the wrong way to do it.

Since then, though, I think I've figured out that something else was causing my problems:

1. I had an Android emulator process (emulator-arm.ese *32) which
   hadn't terminated properly.
2. When I selected another device, I hadn't
   given the (slow) Android emulator enough time to clear the "The
   selected device is incompatible" error(s).

The problem process stayed in Windows' Task Manager after I shut down Android Studio, and Task Manager's  failed to kill it.
So I rebooted my PC, and now everything seems to work OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the multitask button on the emulator itself to open the list of running apps, then click the "X" to close your app.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
You answered the question I asked, but I now see that I had asked the wrong question.
[See above.]